# Fourier transform of $\frac{x_i^2}{|x|^2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

For a function $f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, it is natural to define the Fourier transform as
$$\mathscr{F}(f)(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{-ix\cdot \xi}dx.$$
And the we may extend it to rapidly decreasing functions, Schwartz functions (distributions). And it is easy to verify that 
$$\mathscr{F}(1)=\delta,$$
the Dirac $\delta$ function.

My question is that how to prove that 
$$\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{x_i^2}{|x|^2}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\delta.$$

My intuition is to use the rotational invariance. But I could not proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(\alpha,\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-\frac\alpha2 |x|^2} e^{-i x\cdot\xi} \frac{x_1^2}{|x|^2} \, dx .$$
Consider $\frac d{d\alpha} f(\alpha,\xi)$.  It splits as the product of lots of one-dimensional integrals, each of which can be explicitly computed.  Now get
$$ \mathcal F\left(\frac{x_1^2}{|x|^2}\right) = f(0,\xi) = - \int_0^\infty \frac d{d\alpha} f(\alpha,\xi) \, d\alpha .$$
You will probably get something like
$$ \mathcal F\left(\frac{x_1^2}{|x|^2}\right) = \text{principle value} \left(\frac{c}{|\xi|^n} - \frac{c n \xi_1^2}{|\xi|^{n+2}}\right) + \theta,$$
where $c$ is some explicit constant, and $\theta$ is only at the origin.

To figure out what happens at the origin, sum both sides from $i=1$ to $n$, to get
$$ \mathcal F (1) = n \theta = \delta ,$$
so $ \theta = \frac1n \delta$.

Comment: I did a proper calculation in 2 dimensions, taking the Fourier transform of $|x|^2 \frac{1}{|x|^2}=1,$ then using $\mathcal{F}\{\frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^2} = -\partial_i \partial_j \mathcal{F}\{\frac{1}{|x|^2}\}$ and distributional definition of derivatives, and got
$$
\mathcal{F}\left( \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^2} \right)
= \delta_{ij} \pi\delta + \frac{\delta_{ij}|\xi|^2 - 2\xi_i \xi_j}{|\xi|^4}
$$
(modulo some constant factor).

Comment: @md2perpe It does depend on which definition of Fourier transform is used.